# Window is not showing up at all in VSCode (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying out tkinter in Visual Studio Code and there is no window showing up for this code (just testing):

```
from tkinter import * 
Tk()
```

Did I miss any installations?

Comment: Without a call to `.mainloop()`, your script will end instantly, perhaps before the window was ever visible.

Comment: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Using Tk() alone will only create an instance of the frame, you need the `mainloop()` option to keep the application object in a loop.

Try this code:

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()

window.title('Hello Python')
window.geometry("300x200+10+20")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue. otherwise good answer

Comment: Thank you for the advice @Matiiss, have updated the code in accordance to your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

have you done the installation? if you haven't done the tkinter installation, this is installation guide

for windows :

1. To create a new Conda Python environment named <env_name> and install python 3.8, open an Anaconda Prompt or terminal and enter:

   $ conda create --name <env_name> python=3.8
2. To activate the new environment that has Python 3.8, and switch to it, enter:

   $ activate <env_name>

To verify whether Tkinter is installed ready to be loaded by Python, run the following code in a Python console:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter._test()
```

src: https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-install-tkinter-in-windows/

for mac :

1. Make sure Python and pip is preinstalled on your system

to check python version :

```
python --version
```

to check pip :

```
pip -V
```

2. Install Tkinter

   pip install tk

This command will start downloading and installing packages related to the Tkinter library. Once done, the message of successful installation will be displayed.

src : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-install-tkinter-in-python

Comment: tkinter is a built-in, so unless it was explicitly not installed when installing python, it should be in the system, also the problem is quite obvious and that it is not using `.mainloop()`, also by the look of the source it is pretty old source and seems to be meant for python2 (which is deprecated btw), also why use Conda and stuff, did you just copy paste what was said on those webpages?

Comment: sorry i didnt realize, im just copying paste on those webpages, nice cover thanks a lot man